# Angular material arabic on-screen keyboard

Tags: angular, angular-material, arabic, virtual-keyboard, on-screen-keyboard

I am trying to implement an on-screen keyboard with arabic layout on angular 14 with material design. Is there any npm packages which is easier to get this, I just tried to implement some of the packages but the packages are failed to meet the status.

Some of the packages make the application broken and some them are not even installing. The keyboard should be shown only when on focus and go on when the focus is out.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

npm install simple-keyboard-layouts --save

or you can follow this tuto:

https://hodgef.com/simple-keyboard/modules/simple-keyboard-layouts/